# ワールド内での任意処理実行について

Tags: unity3d

Clusterの学習を始めました。
最終的にやりたいことにClusterが合致しているかわからず、識者の皆さんに教えを請いたい次第です。

**やりたいこと**
ワールド内部からJavaScritやC#のコードを使って、外部のプラットフォームと認可フローを構築したい。

具体的には
ワールド内部の特定のオブジェクトを触るなどのギミックをトリガーにして
Oauthの認可フローを回したいと考えています。

**困っているポイント**

ワールド内のオブジェクトのイベント処理をかけるのは理解したのですが、
任意のコードを埋め込めるようにはなっていないように見受けられます（テンプレートの中から選択)
このまま学習を進めて到達できるのか、わからず。

- そんなことできないよ当たり前じゃん
- Oauthのフローなら、すでにテンプレートあるからそれを使うんだよ。
- マニュアルのここにあるから読んでみろ
- お金をかければできるよ

などのヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

**環境情報**

Cluster 2.72
UnityHub 3.4.1
ClusterKitSample 2021.3.4f1

Answer (score 0):

本件
C#などによる直接的な処理実行は不可能であるとの見解をえましたので、
クローズさせていただきます。